# Is it possible to tell Craft to ignore requests to under a certain path?

Tags: routes

Unfortunately, I'm in a position where I need to run a Craft and WordPress installation out of the same directory. The WordPress install is under the sub-directory `/blog`.

When I visit `http://mysite.dev/blog/` the WordPress blog loads as expected, but attempts to visit any routes within that result in Craft's 404 page. For instance, `http://mysite.dev/blog/my-post`.

Is it possible to convince Craft to ignore any requests under `/blog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Routing article](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) in the Craft Documentation, it describes why Craft handles these request in the first place:

> The **.htaccess** file that comes with Craft will redirect all would-be 404 requests over to index.php behind the scenes, which is why Craft is able to respond to URLs that don’t point to any actual folder/file in your web root.

A fresh Craft install's `.htaccess` file looks like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You'll notice that favicons are removed from the redirect. Add a similar `RewriteCond` for `blog/` to also exclude request to your  WordPress folder from this condition.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog [NC]
```

Comment: You are a machine, @carlcs.