# Localized Craft Build with Vanilla Forums?

Tags: mamp

Anyone have any luck getting a localized Craft build working with a localized Vanilla Forums install?

I've got MAMP installed, in conjunction with CodeKit. Craft itself is running fine. I installed the Vanilla Forums directory under the Templates directory. Whenever I visit craft.dev/vanilla(MAMP) or macbook.local:5757/vanilla (CodeKit) in my browser, I get a Page Not Found error. If I go straight to the index.php file, it spews out the actual ph

Comment: but isn't vanilla forums a stand-alone website ?

Comment: Sorry, guess I didn't make myself clear. I downloaded the open-source version from http://vanillaforums.org/. There's a hosted version available at http://vanillaforums.com, but I'm not going that route.

Comment: “under the Templates directory” as in craft/templates/?

Answer (score 2):

If you install a secondary app within your Craft directory, you have to tell Craft to ignore all these requests. Just edit your `.htaccess` file accordingly.

See my answer here on how you can do this: ["Is it possible to tell Craft to ignore requests to under a certain path?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1964/125)