# What's the correct directory setup for Craft with Vanilla Forums?

Tags: setup

I'm looking in to setting up a new site which has a Craft site in front of the open source version of Vanilla Forums. I'm a bit stuck on exactly where I should put vanilla though, and how to access it on the front end.

At the moment I've got this setup:

```
/
    /craft
    /public
        /vanilla
```

But then vanilla's URLs look like `http://domain.dev/vanilla/index.php?p=` and it seems to conflic with Craft's .htaccess.

I've also seen on [another question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/localized-craft-build-with-vanilla-forums) that someone installed vanilla in the templates directory. Is that better or a bad idea?

Lastly, should I be trying to run the forums under something like `domain.dev/forums/`, or would it be easier to run it on a subdomain like `forums.domain.dev`? I'm going to be using the [Single Sign On plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/vanillaforums) to integrate it with Craft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daryl,

I've setup a few sites with Craft and Vanilla Forums, I've always named the folder "Vanilla" to either "Community" or "Forum" so the url being "vanilla" isn't a problem. Also you should know you can do a javascript include into another craft template so the URL can be anything you want really. I've never had a .htaccess conflict though.

I've always run the forums under /forums or /community or something of the sort when not using the javascript iframe embed method at which point the url can be anything. I've never attempted using a sub-domain, just did not see the point.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Followup for anyone else who finds this question - the vanilla folder is going to live in `/public`