# Have Craft deliver single page despite having a directory of the same name in the public folder?

Tags: routing, htaccess

I just switched my company's website to Craft, and I have a lot of already existing static webpages that I would rather not remake as templates and define routes for. I have a single page made in Craft at /events, but when I add the subdirectory events/event-name, going to /events presents a 403 error. I know why this is happening, because of the way Craft handles routing, but is there any way (possibly in my .htaccess file) for going to /events to deliver the single page like normal, despite having the subdirectory in my public folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could update the links to your static HTML to point to the files directly

`http://mygreatnewcraftsite.com/events/myoldstaticfile.html`

or modify your .htaccess file like I described here: ["Is it possible to tell Craft to ignore requests to under a certain path?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1966/125)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think this is going in the right direction. What I need is site.com and `site.com/events` to go to Craft, but to have a static site (with stylesheets, images, etc) at the directory `/htdocs/events/event-name`. However, if the `/htdocs/events` exists, Apache delivers a 403. I want `site.com/events` to go to Craft, but `site.com/events/event-name` to go to the static site.