# Install Craft in a subfolder of an ee site?

Tags: install

I have an ee site which I can't move over to Craft yet (need a commenting plugin) but I need to extend the site quite a bit. I'm thinking of either installing Craft in a subdomain or a subfolder.

In a Friday chat Brandon advised to go with a subdomain, as having Craft in a subfolder of an ee site that I would/might run into session problems.

Is installing Craft into a subfolder of an ee site a complete no no, or are the potential session problems avoidable? Anything else to lookout for?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additional to the potential session headaches, you'd also have to worry about getting the `.htaccess` rewrite rules to play together for each installation considering they inherit from any parent folders.

Comment: See this question to see how to modify .htaccess http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1964/